# Sheet displayed several times in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-sheet

Short description: in detailView I've got a List of a related entity. For each item, there's a button to open the edit sheet for this item.

```
List {
  if (book.booksBorrowers != nil) {
    ForEach (Array(book.booksBorrowers! as! Set<Borrowers>), id: \.self) { borrower in
      HStack {
        Text(borrower.firstName ?? "unbekannter Vorname")
        Text(borrower.lastName ?? "unbekannter Nachname")
        Text(String(format: "%.0f", borrower.age))
        Spacer()
        Button {
          showingBorrowerEditScreen.toggle()
        } label: {
          Image(systemName: "pencil")
            .frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
        }.multilineTextAlignment(.center).buttonStyle(.borderless)
          .sheet(isPresented: $showingBorrowerEditScreen) {
          EditBorrowerView(
            aBorrower: borrower,
            firstName: borrower.firstName!,
            lastName: borrower.lastName!,
            age: Int(borrower.age)
            
          ).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.viewContext)
        }
      }
    }.onDelete(perform: deleteBorrower)
  }
}.listStyle(.inset(alternatesRowBackgrounds: true))
```

On clicking one of the edit button within the list, a sheet appears with an edit form, prefilled with the values of the selected list item.

```
struct EditBorrowerView: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  
  @State private var firstName = ""
  @State private var lastName = ""
  @State private var age = 0.0
  
  @StateObject var aBorrower: Borrowers

  init(aBorrower: Borrowers, firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int) {
    self._aBorrower = StateObject(wrappedValue: aBorrower)
    self._firstName = State(initialValue: aBorrower.firstName ?? "")
    self._lastName = State(initialValue: aBorrower.lastName ?? "")
    self._age = State(initialValue: Double(aBorrower.age))
  }
  let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    return formatter
  }()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Ausleiher bearbeiten").font(.title)
      Form {
        VStack {
          TextField("Vorname", text: $firstName)
          TextField("Nachname", text: $lastName)
          HStack {
            Slider(value: $age, in: 0...99, step: 1)
            TextField("Alter", value: $age, formatter: formatter)
          }
        }
      }
      HStack {
        Button("Save") {
          // save the edited book
          aBorrower.firstName = firstName
          aBorrower.lastName = lastName
          aBorrower.age = Double(age)
          
          try? moc.save()
          dismiss()
        }
        Button("Cancel") {
          dismiss()
        }
      }
    }.padding(10)
  }
}
```

But now, when clicking the edit button of a row

- a) only the content of the first list item is shown in the displayed form
- b) clicking cancel in the sheet, the sheet will appear for every item in the list before disappearing, containing the respective values.

A small debugging with print() shows, that on clicking the edit button the correct values are set first (e.g. I click on third item, values of third item are passed), but additionally, all list items are passed to the sheet, too.

---

[First image as example of upper question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OyRZ.jpg)

[Second image as example of upper question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Caus8.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a `.sheet(isPresented:)` modifier in a view that is repeated in a loop, but your boolean state variable is outside the loop, then that one state variable is used for multiple copies of the sheet. Sometimes that may manifest as a sheet showing with details different to the row you clicked on; other times you might see multiple sheets. It sounds like the side effects you're seeing are related to this.

There are a couple of ways you can get around this.

### Option 1 - `sheet(item:)`

Replace your `showingBorrowerEditScreen` with a `borrowerToEdit` state variable that is an optional object, defaulting to nil:

```
@State private var borrowerToEdit: Borrower? = nil
```

In your button action, set this to the borrower of the current row in the loop:

```
Button {
  borrowerToEdit = borrower
} label: {
  // etc
```

And finally, use the `item:` form of the sheet modifier **outside the `ForEach` loop**. Note that this form takes a block with a reference to the borrower object concerned.

```
ForEach(...) { borrower in
  // etc.
}
.sheet(item: $borrowerToEdit) { borrower in 
  EditBorrowerView(
    aBorrower: borrower,
    firstName: borrower.firstName!,
    lastName: borrower.lastName!,
    age: Int(borrower.age)            
  )
}
```

### Option 2 - individual subviews

If you want to stick with booleans to represent whether a modal sheet should be used, you'll need to isolate that boolean to its own subview, by extracting the row details. For example:

```
List {
  if (book.booksBorrowers != nil) {
    ForEach (Array(book.booksBorrowers! as! Set<Borrowers>), id: \.self) { borrower in
      BorrowerListRow(borrower: borrower)
      .onDelete(perform: deleteBorrower)
    }
  }
}

struct BorrowerListRow: View {
  @ObservedObject var borrower: Borrower
  @State private var showingBorrowerEditScreen = false

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Text(borrower.firstName ?? "unbekannter Vorname")
      Text(borrower.lastName ?? "unbekannter Nachname")
      Text(String(format: "%.0f", borrower.age))
      Spacer()
      Button {
        showingBorrowerEditScreen.toggle()
      } label: {
        Image(systemName: "pencil")
          .frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
      }.multilineTextAlignment(.center).buttonStyle(.borderless)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingBorrowerEditScreen) {
          EditBorrowerView(
            aBorrower: borrower,
            firstName: borrower.firstName!,
            lastName: borrower.lastName!,
            age: Int(borrower.age)
          ).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.viewContext)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

That way, each row has its own "should I be showing a modal" Boolean, so there can be no confusion about which row "owns" the active sheet, and only one will be able to be shown at a time.

---

Which option you go for is partly down to personal preference. I tend to favour option 1 in my own code, as it feels more that the modal is "owned" by the list rather than a row, and it reinforces the idea that you can only edit one borrower at a time. But either approach should eliminate the problems you're currently seeing.

Comment: You made my day!! Thanks for your great help. Solution 2 is the best way and works fine.